# Google Visualization Throwing "length of null" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, google-visualization

I am developing an application using Flask as the framework. I am using 
[Google Visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference?hl=en) for drawing graphs. The graphs are displayed on carousel slider. Four graphs are shown in one slider. The first one displays correctly. When I am trying to draw graphs on next slider, it is behaving weirdly and throwing errors. Please find images below:

**Correct Output in First Page:**

[image: Correct Output]

**Error in Second Page:**
[image: error in second page]

I have been struggling for the past 2 days to fix this issue but couldn't succeed. I am not able to find out what the issue is. Can anyone correct me where I am going wrong?

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="100; URL=http://127.0.0.1:5000/">
    <title>Test</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    
    <link href="static/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="static/css/new.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="static/lib/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
     <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="static/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>    
    <script src="static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/Chart.js-master/Chart.js"></script> 
</head>

<body onload = onLoading()>
<div class="container">
<div class="col-xs-12">

    <div class="page-header">
        <h3><b>Test</b></h3>       
    </div>

    <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
        <nav>
            <ul class="control-box pager">
                <li><a data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" class=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a></li>
                <li><a data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel" class=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
       <!-- /.control-box -->
       <!-- Slide1 -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" id="imp">
            <!-- /Slide1 -->            
        </div><!-- /Carousel inner -->                              
    </div><!-- /#myCarousel -->        
</div><!-- /.col-xs-12 -->  
</div><!-- /.container -->


<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
// Carousel Auto-Cycle
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 3000
    })
  });


function onLoading()

{    
//alert("Inside");      
$.get("/load",function(calldata,status)
{
//console.log(calldata);
//alert(calldata.length);
var num_nodes = calldata.length;  
var loop = 0;

for(i=0;i<num_nodes;i++)
{

    if(i%4==0)
    {
        if(i==0)
        {
            var divoutput = document.getElementById("imp");
            var divhtml = '<div class="item active" id="c'+(i/4)+'"></div>';           
            divoutput.innerHTML = divoutput.innerHTML+divhtml;
            alert(i);
            console.log(divoutput.innerHTML);
        }
        else
        {
            var divoutput = document.getElementById("imp");
            var divhtml = '<div class="item" id="c'+(i/4)+'"></div>';
            divoutput.innerHTML = divoutput.innerHTML+divhtml;
            loop = i/4;
            alert(loop);
            console.log(divoutput.innerHTML);

        }
    }
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Errors');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Statistics');
    data.addRows([
          ['Success',     calldata[i].errors.success],
          ['Authorization Failure', calldata[i].errors.auth_failure],
          ['Feature Failure',  calldata[i].errors.feature_failure],
          ['FSOL Failure', calldata[i].errors.fsol_failure] 
        ]);


    var options = {
          title: calldata[i].node_name,
          is3D: true,
          backgroundColor:'#ECECEA',

        };


    var output = document.getElementById("c"+loop);
    //alert("***"+document.getElementById("c"+loop));
    var html = '<div class="col-sm-6"><div class="fff"><div class="thumbnail" id="i'+i+'"></div></div></div>';
    //alert(html);
    output.innerHTML = output.innerHTML + html;
    var tmp = "i";
    var ele_id = tmp.concat(i);
    //alert(ele_id);
    if(calldata[i].errors.success < calldata[i].errors.auth_failure)
    {
        document.getElementById("i"+i).style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart(ele_id,data,options)); 
}
});  
}

function drawChart(ele_id,data,options) 
{
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});  
    //alert(ele_id);  
    //alert("draw"+document.getElementById(ele_id));
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(ele_id));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you set a height and width for the graphs? Post your code

Comment: @Kyle Sorry about that. Updated with my code :)

Comment: I'd recommend you to change your title to something more descriptive, so it is more likely to get an answer

Comment: @T3H40 Thank you for ur suggestion. Updated title accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure about how this would apply to you, but it looks like you draw all the charts at the same time, even the ones "hidden" (not showing in the carousel). Try to organize it to draw the charts once you show the div, and not when it's hidden. I'd also recommend to save the state (drawn/not drawn) somehow, so you won't have to redraw them once they show up again.